# how to find the objects dependent on the database collation

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, collation

I got a problem during changing the database collation in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 as:

> The object 'XXX' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it.

So, I want to know the list of Objects dependent on database collation.

Comment: [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/39321443-c2f9-4275-a571-1d3b1d52b51c/how-to-change-database-collation?forum=sqldatabaseengine) may help

Comment: Thnks @ughai

But i want to know the procedure to find out all the objects which are dependent on database collation for a particular database.

Is it possible? if yes, then how can proceed.